# Wordpress remove br tags on one specific page or page template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have seen people remove br tags from wordpress by adding the following to the functions file:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );

remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

I would like this to affect only one page or page template. Is there any good way to do this? Like use a template name comparison in the functions.php?

EDIT:

For example I have tried the following without result in functions.php for my theme:

```
if( is_page_template("template_file_name.php") ){
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );

    remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you want to do? from what I understands. ( a page design is broken from a br tag, and you want to remove all BR on that page template ONLY ) ?

Comment: Wordpress has a habit of adding br tags to page content. It works fine on most pages, but for one page with custom content, it makes things look ugly. I want to remove br tags from content on one page only (or page template).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to remove all br

can you try targeting that page with css? 
This will give the most flexibility

```
.page-id-123 .content br { display:none; }
```

Comment: Proper setup was to include css to the page and set form br { display:none; }